# Spark 3 structured streaming use maxOffsetsPerTrigger in Kafka source with Trigger.Once

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

We need to use `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` in the Kafka source with `Trigger.Once()` in structured streaming but based on this [issue](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27380) it seems reads `allAvailable` in spark 3. Is there a way for achieving rate limit in this situation?

Here is a sample code in spark 3:

```
def options: Map[String, String] = Map(
  "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> conf.getStringSeq("bootstrapServers").mkString(","),
  "subscribe" -> conf.getString("topic")
) ++
  Option(conf.getLong("maxOffsetsPerTrigger")).map("maxOffsetsPerTrigger" -> _.toString)
val streamingQuery = sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka").options(options)
  .load
  .writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.Once)
  .start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way around it to properly set a rate limit. If the `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` is not applicable for streaming jobs with the `Once` trigger you could do the following to achieve identical result:

1. Choose another trigger and use `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` to limit the rate and kill this job manually after it finished processing all data.
2. Use options `startingOffsets` and `endingOffsets` while making the job a *batch* job. Repeat until you have processed all data within the topic. However, there is a reason why "Streaming in RunOnce mode is better than Batch" as detailed [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html).

Last option would be to look into the linked pull request and compile Spark on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how we "solved" this. This is basically the approach `mike` wrote about in the accepted answer.

In our case, the size of the message varied very little and we therefore knew how much time the processing of a batch takes. So in a nutshell we:

- changed the `Trigger.Once()` with `Trigger.ProcessingTime(<ms>)` since `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` works with this mode
- killed this running query by calling `awaitTermination(<ms>)` to mimic `Trigger.Once()`
- set the processing interval to be larger than the termination interval so exactly one "batch" would fit to be processed

```scala
val kafkaOptions = Map[String, String](
      "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "failOnDataLoss" -> "false",
      "subscribePattern" -> "testTopic",
      "startingOffsets" -> "earliest",
      "maxOffsetsPerTrigger" -> "10",  // "batch" size
    )

val streamWriterOptions = Map[String, String](
    "checkpointLocation" -> "path/to/checkpoints",
  )

val processingInterval = 30000L
val terminationInterval = 15000L

sparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .options(kafkaOptions)
      .load()
      .writeStream
      .options(streamWriterOptions)
      .format("Console")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(processingInterval))
      .start()
      .awaitTermination(terminationInterval)
```

This works because the first batch will be read and processed respecting the `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` limit. Say, in 10 seconds. The second batch is then started to be processed but it is terminated in the middle of the operation after ~5s and never reaches the set 30s mark. But it stores the offsets correctly. picks up and processes this "killed" batch in the next run.

A downside of this approach is that you have to approximately know how much time does it take to process one "batch" - if you set the `terminationInterval` too low the job's output will constantly be nothing.

Of course, if you don't care about the exact number of batches you process in one run, you can easily adjust the `processingInterval` to be times smaller than the `terminationInterval`. In that case, you may process a varying number of batches in one go but still respecting the value of `maxOffsetsPerTrigger`.

Answer (score 0):

With Spark 3.3.0 you should be able to use Trigger.AvailableNow as discussed in Bartosz's excellent blog: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/what-new-apache-spark-3.3.0-structured-streaming/read

I say *should* because as I'm playing around with it I haven't quite got it to work, and will be posting a question around this shortly.